# phpmyadmin I can't directly edit a table field

Tags: phpmyadmin

In my database I have a table 'tbl_product'. In this table I have a field called 'fk_status_id'. When I try to change its value in phpMyAdmin it gives the error "Unknown column 'fk_status_id' in 'field list' which is clearly incorrect as the field obviously exists.

Can anyone please explain what is going on here?

Thanks, G.

Comment: Maybe the column name contains some “special character” (entered by accident at creation time), which phpMyAdmin does not handle correctly or filter out. The raw output of a [SHOW COLUMNS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-columns.html) statement could help verify that.

Comment: Hi, the SHOW COLUMS statement shows up nothing out of the ordinary. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

After investigating a little further I notice that any fields added after the 'fk_status_id' field also have the same problem. I dropped both of them and re-created them nearer the top of the table and the problem is solved. I can't explain why this should be so, and I'd still welcome any feed back on the issue.